# How can I use Apache Daffodil's DataProcessor.unparse() method to reconstitute the original parsed message?

Tags: java, parsing, dfdl

I am a beginner to Apache Daffodil.

I used Daffodil Java API to parse input text message successfully to XML string i.e.,

```
        Compiler dfdlCompiler = Daffodil.compiler();
        dfdlCompiler.setValidateDFDLSchemas(true);
        File schemaFile = this.getFileFromResources("EDIFACT-SupplyChain-D03B/EDIFACT-SupplyChain-Messages-D.03B.xsd");
        ProcessorFactory processorFactory = dfdlCompiler.compileFile(schemaFile);
        DataProcessor dataProcessor = processorFactory.onPath("/");
        java.io.File file = getFileFromResources("TestData/ORDERS_D.03B_Interchange.txt");
        java.io.FileInputStream fis = new java.io.FileInputStream(file);
        InputSourceDataInputStream dis = new InputSourceDataInputStream(fis);
        JDOMInfosetOutputter outputter = new JDOMInfosetOutputter();
        ParseResult parseResult = dataProcessor.parse(dis, outputter);
        Document doc = outputter.getResult().getDocument();
        XMLOutputter xo = new XMLOutputter(org.jdom2.output.Format.getPrettyFormat());
        String xmlString = xo.outputString(doc);

        System.out.println("parsed text... resulting xmlString=" + xmlString);
```

But, now, I am unclear on how to use the unparse() method to reconstitute the original text message (seems there's a dearth of examples on using Daffodil's Java API to unparse to reconstitute the original message).

Trying this:

```
        SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
        Document d2 = builder.build(new StringReader(xmlString));
        JDOMInfosetInputter inputter = new JDOMInfosetInputter(d2);
        WritableByteChannel output = Channels.newChannel(new DataOutputStream(new ByteArrayOutputStream()));
        UnparseResult result = dataProcessor.unparse(inputter, output);
```

How can I extract the original message?  Or, is this approach incorrect?

Apache Daffodil version:  2.3

Java version:  jdk8+

---

Testing with this somewhat cut-down Java app...

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.channels.Channels;
import java.nio.channels.WritableByteChannel;
import org.jdom2.Document;
import org.jdom2.output.XMLOutputter;

import org.apache.daffodil.japi.Compiler;
import org.apache.daffodil.japi.Daffodil;
import org.apache.daffodil.japi.DataProcessor;
import org.apache.daffodil.japi.ParseResult;
import org.apache.daffodil.japi.ProcessorFactory;
import org.apache.daffodil.japi.UnparseResult;
import org.apache.daffodil.japi.infoset.JDOMInfosetInputter;
import org.apache.daffodil.japi.infoset.JDOMInfosetOutputter;
import org.apache.daffodil.japi.io.InputSourceDataInputStream;
import org.jdom2.input.SAXBuilder;

public class Blah2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, Exception {
        Blah2 b = new Blah2();
        b.process();
    }

    private void process() throws IOException, Exception {

        Compiler dfdlCompiler = Daffodil.compiler();
        dfdlCompiler.setValidateDFDLSchemas(true);
        File schemaFile = this.getFileFromResources("EDIFACT-SupplyChain-D03B/EDIFACT-SupplyChain-Messages-D.03B.xsd");
        ProcessorFactory processorFactory = dfdlCompiler.compileFile(schemaFile);
        DataProcessor dataProcessor = processorFactory.onPath("/");
        java.io.File file = getFileFromResources("TestData/ORDERS_D.03B_Interchange.txt");
        java.io.FileInputStream fis = new java.io.FileInputStream(file);
        InputSourceDataInputStream dis = new InputSourceDataInputStream(fis);
        JDOMInfosetOutputter outputter = new JDOMInfosetOutputter();
        ParseResult parseResult = dataProcessor.parse(dis, outputter);
        Document doc = outputter.getResult().getDocument();
        XMLOutputter xo = new XMLOutputter(org.jdom2.output.Format.getPrettyFormat());
        String xmlString = xo.outputString(doc);

        System.out.println("parsed text... resulting xmlString=" + xmlString);

        SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
        Document d2 = builder.build(new StringReader(xmlString));
        JDOMInfosetInputter inputter = new JDOMInfosetInputter(d2);
        WritableByteChannel output = Channels.newChannel(new DataOutputStream(new ByteArrayOutputStream()));
        UnparseResult result = dataProcessor.unparse(inputter, output);

        System.out.println("unparsed xml document.. result.toString()=" + String.valueOf(result));        

        //how can I obtain the original input text???
    }

    private File getFileFromResources(String fileName) throws IOException {
        URL resource = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(fileName);
        return new File(resource.getFile());
    }
}
```

Output of parse operation is below.

(I still don't understand how I can accomplish the reverse - i.e., "unparse")

```
parsed text... resulting xmlString=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<D03B:Interchange xmlns:D03B="http://www.ibm.com/dfdl/edi/un/edifact/SupplyChain/D03B">
  <UNB>
    <S001>
      <E0001>UNOA</E0001>
      <E0002>4</E0002>
    </S001>
    <S002>
      <E0004>APPLICATION</E0004>
      <E0007>1</E0007>
    </S002>
    <S003>
      <E0010>COMPANY</E0010>
      <E0007>1</E0007>
    </S003>
    <S004>
      <E0017>20051107</E0017>
      <E0019>1159</E0019>
    </S004>
    <E0020>6002</E0020>
  </UNB>
  <D03B:Message>
    <UNH>
      <E0062>SSDD1</E0062>
      <S009>
        <E0065>ORDERS</E0065>
        <E0052>D</E0052>
        <E0054>03B</E0054>
        <E0051>UN</E0051>
        <E0057>EAN008</E0057>
      </S009>
    </UNH>
    <D03B:BadMessage>
      <Segment>
        <Name>BGM</Name>
        <Data>2B3232302B424B4F4439392B39</Data>
      </Segment>
      <Segment>
        <Name>DTM</Name>
        <Data>2B3133373A32303035313130373A313032</Data>
      </Segment>
      <Segment>
        <Name>NAD</Name>
        <Data>2B42592B353431323334353030303137363A3A39</Data>
      </Segment>
      <Segment>
        <Name>NAD</Name>
        <Data>2B53552B343031323334353030303039343A3A39</Data>
      </Segment>
      <Segment>
        <Name>CTA</Name>
        <Data>2B4141</Data>
      </Segment>
      <Segment>
        <Name>COM</Name>
        <Data>2B7331313A41412A7332313A41412A7333313A4141</Data>
      </Segment>
      <Segment>
        <Name>LIN</Name>
        <Data>2B312B312B303736343536393130343A4942</Data>
      </Segment>
      <Segment>
        <Name>QTY</Name>
        <Data>2B313A3235</Data>
      </Segment>
      <Segment>
        <Name>FTX</Name>
        <Data>2B41464D2B312B2B4C6F7264206F66207468652052696E6773</Data>
      </Segment>
      <Segment>
        <Name>LIN</Name>
        <Data>2B322B312B303736343536393039303A4942</Data>
      </Segment>
      <Segment>
        <Name>QTY</Name>
        <Data>2B313A3235</Data>
      </Segment>
      <Segment>
        <Name>FTX</Name>
        <Data>2B41464D2B312B2B54686520486F62626974</Data>
      </Segment>
      <Segment>
        <Name>LIN</Name>
        <Data>2B332B312B313836313030343635363A4942</Data>
      </Segment>
      <Segment>
        <Name>QTY</Name>
        <Data>2B313A3136</Data>
      </Segment>
      <Segment>
        <Name>FTX</Name>
        <Data>2B41464D2B312B2B5468652053696C6D6172696C6C696F6E</Data>
      </Segment>
      <Segment>
        <Name>LIN</Name>
        <Data>2B342B312B303539363030363735363A4942</Data>
      </Segment>
      <Segment>
        <Name>QTY</Name>
        <Data>2B313A3130</Data>
      </Segment>
      <Segment>
        <Name>FTX</Name>
        <Data>2B41464D2B312B2B546865204368696C6472656E206F6620487572696E</Data>
      </Segment>
      <Segment>
        <Name>UNS</Name>
        <Data>2B53</Data>
      </Segment>
      <Segment>
        <Name>CNT</Name>
        <Data>2B323A34</Data>
      </Segment>
    </D03B:BadMessage>
    <UNT>
      <E0074>22</E0074>
      <E0062>SSDD1</E0062>
    </UNT>
  </D03B:Message>
  <UNZ>
    <E0036>1</E0036>
    <E0020>6002</E0020>
  </UNZ>
</D03B:Interchange>

unparsed xml document.. result.toString()=org.apache.daffodil.japi.UnparseResult@2e734540
```

Comment: I see you open `TestData/ORDERS_D.03B_Interchange.txt` and parse it with respect to DFDL schema `EDIFACT-SupplyChain-D03B/EDIFACT-SupplyChain-Messages-D.03B.xsd`.  Q: Does that give you the expected XML?  Q: What exactly happens when you try to "unparse()" that XML document?  Do you get anything at all?

Comment: Hi paulsm4 - posted the output.   again, I can compile and parse w/o errors - but, still unclear how to accomplish the reverse operation - i.e., "unparse()".  appreciate any help/example

Comment: btw - i'm using the UN/EDIFACT schema publically available on GitHub - as well as the sample message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UnparseResult` actual doesn't contain the result of the unparse (yeah, maybe we could name that better ;). The `UnparseResult` actually just contains whether or not the unparse succeeded (via the `isError` method) and any diagnostics when something fails. The unparse data is written to the `WritableByteChannel` that you pass into `unparse()` as a parameter.

The problem is that in your case, you have the following to define that channel:

```java
WritableByteChannel output = Channels.newChannel(new DataOutputStream(new ByteArrayOutputStream()));
```

So the channel you've defined writes to the underlying `ByteArrayOutputStream`, but you don't have any access to those bytes because it's not assigned to a variable. So really what you want to do is assign a `ByteArrayOutputStream` to a variable and pass it to your new channel and then access the byte array after the unparse--something like this:

```java
ByteArrayOutputStream boas = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
WritableByteChannel output = Channels.newChannel(new DataOutputStream(boas));
UnparseResult result = dataProcessor.unparse(inputter, output);
System.out.println(boas.toString());
```

Also, some good resources for Daffodil Java API usage are our Java API tests here:

https://github.com/apache/incubator-daffodil/blob/master/daffodil-japi/src/test/java/org/apache/daffodil/example/TestJavaAPI.java

That has examples of using the ByteArrayOutputStream and WritableByteChannel to unparse bytes and convert to a string.

Comment: Thx, Steve!  Tremendously closer thanks to you! :-)     -Unfortunately, the output of boas.toString() - i.e., UNB+UNOA:4+APPLICATION:1+COMPANY:1+20051107:1159+6002'  - is much shorter than the original message.  Not sure why that is yet.  (as I indicated, I am a supreme newby when it comes to Daffodil [of DFDL] processing).   I'll will still mark your's as the accepted answer - because I am at least getting some of the output (orig message) I am seeking - where before I had nothing

Comment: If you aren't already, you might try the recently release 2.4.0. This version greatly improves compatability with many of the schemas on https://github.com/DFDLSchemas , including EDIFACT. If that doesn't fix it, you might also try the mailing lists ( https://daffodil.apache.org/community/ ). Debugging schema issues can sometimes take multiple back and forths, which is usually a little easier to do over email.